# How to get the last value of a specific id in an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a function that store the values of a row in an array onkeyup event. However, there are instances that it would store the same row values but differ on quantity and total but the same id. How would I store it in the array in a way that it would just save the most current set of values of an specific id? I know it's a bit confusing, but please take a look in the image below. Thank you for the help.

[image]

I would like to save the ff:

```
{id:"1", qty:"4", price:"45", total:"180"}
{id:"2", qty:"3", price:"10", total:"30"}
{id:"3", qty:"50", price:"12", total:"600"}
{id:"4", qty:"60", price:"12", total:"720"}
```

My Code:

```
var arrayVar = [];
var data;

$(function(){

  $('#tbl-po-list').on( 'keyup change' , 'input[type="number"]' ,function(){

    $(this).parents('.info').find('.total').val($(this).val() * $(this).parents('.info').find('.price').val());

      data = {
        id: $(this).parents('.info').find('.prod-id').val(),
        qty: $(this).val(),
        price: $(this).parents('.info').find('.price').val(),
        total: $(this).parents('.info').find('.total').val()
      }

      arrayVar.push(data); 

      for(var i = 0; i < arrayVar.length; i++){
        console.log(arrayVar[i]);
      }

    });   

  });
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that if you replace:

```
arrayVar.push(data);
```

by:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayVar.length; i++){
    if (arrayVar[i].id === data.id) break; // found the same id!
}
arrayVar[i] = data;
```

If the loop does not find the same *id*, then after the loop *i* will equal *arrayVar.length*, and so the assignment will be like a push.

If on the other hand the *id* is found, then the loop exits, and the assignment will replace whatever was in that array element before.

A more concise version of the same:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayVar.length && arrayVar[i].id !== data.id; i++);
arrayVar[i] = data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems ripe for some code golf. Here's my attempt:

```
o=data.reduce((a,v)=>a[v.id]=v&&a,{});Object.keys(o).map(k=>o[k]);
```

Original code:

```
obj = data.reduce((accum, value, i) => {
  accum[value.id] = value;
  return accum;
})
out = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```

This works by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate values into an object - using the id as the key means rows with the same ID will get overwritten - and then extracts the values from the object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the array value using `splice()` inside of your for loop if it's found:

```
var id = $(this).parents('.info').find('.prod-id').val();

for(var i = 0; i < arrayVar.length; i++){
   if(arrayVar[i]['id'] == id){
       arrayVar.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/a27x91ay/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate from the end to the beginning pushing only new objects (by id) to a new array. `unshift` keeps the new array in the same order.

```
var index = [], out = [];
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (index.indexOf(arr[i].id) === -1) {
    index.push(arr[i].id);
    out.unshift(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4foz299j/)